# Listing figure citations in order of appearance in the main bibliography list (other answers have not worked)

Tags: bibliographies, floats, citing, natbib

I think there might be something wrong with my code (as I am very new to Latex/overleaf). Note that I am using overleaf. I have seen this question other places too, but the answers are not working for me. Can anyone spot a major mistake in my preamble? Note that I have now not included the other answers in my code.

To be clear: When I cite inside the figure caption, these are listed first in the biblipgraphy list, independent of the order of appearance. How do I make them list in order of appearance?

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage[margin=0.9 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft\parindent

\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage[version = 4]{mhchem} 


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[euler]{textgreek} 

\graphicspath{{Images/}}

\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

\usepackage[numbers,round]{natbib}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Hannan2013,
author = {Hannan, Nicholas R F and Segeritz, Charis-patricia and Touboul Thomas and Vallier, Ludovic},
doi = {10.1038/nprot.2012.153},
issn = {1754-2189},
journal = {Nat. Protoc.},
month = {feb},
number = {2},
pages = {430--437},
title = {{Production of hepatocyte-like cells from human pluripotent stem cells}},
volume = {8},
year = {2013}
}

@article{Lim1980,
author = {Lim, Franklin and Sun, Anthony M.},
doi = {10.1126/science.6776628},
issn = {00368075},
journal = {Science (80-. ).},
number = {4472},
pages = {908--910},
title = {{Microencapsulated islets as bioartificial endocrine pancreas}},
volume = {210},
year = {1980}
}

@article{Dalheim2016,
author = {Dalheim, Marianne and Vanacker, Julie and Najmi, Maryam A. and Aachmann, Finn L. and Strand, Berit L. and Christensen, Bj{\o}rn E.},
doi = {10.1016/j.biomaterials.2015.11.043},
issn = {18785905},
journal = {Biomaterials},
keywords = {Alginate,Cell adhesion,Periodate oxidation,RGD peptide,Reductive amination,Tissue engineering},
pages = {146--156},
title = {{Efficient functionalization of alginate biomaterials}},
volume = {80},
year = {2016}
}

\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{color}

% Setting chapter and section format:
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\rmfamily\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}{20pt}{\LARGE}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{14pt} 
 \titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\rmfamily\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{\Large}
 \titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\rmfamily\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\rmfamily\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0ex}}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{figure} 
\renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{table} 

%------------DOCUMENT-----------
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}


% Preface
    \chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface} 
\setcounter{page}{1}


% Table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables
    {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
        \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables
    }

% Background
    \chapter{Background} 
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

% Introduction
    \chapter{Introduction} 
My very first reference \cite{Hannan2013}, 
and my second reference \cite{Lim1980}.

% Methods
    \chapter{Background} 

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\qquad
\caption{Periodate oxidation \cite{Dalheim2016}.} % Third reference.
\label{fig:periodateOx}
\end{figure}

% Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you supply a compilable MWE. As your Example has external files, this cant be compiled.

Comment: Thank you, I have now edited the document to not include any external files, and it is readily compileable.

Comment: Why not use `\caption[Periodate oxidation.]{Periodate oxidation \cite{Dalheim2016}.}` ?

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't solve the problem for me. Even if the citation does not appear in the list of figures, it is still numbered as 1 in the caption.

Comment: I just had a look at your MWE. The bibliography style that you use sorts the entries in the list of references by last name of first author. (Try to exchange 2 `\cite` commands and you will see that the references will stay in the same order). To sort by order of appraeance, use `unsrtnat` as bibliography style instead.

Comment: You might also want to check the enries of your .bib file. `Science (80-. ).` as a journal seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, now they are ordered correctly!  I tried so many styles to make the first names abbreviated (and appear after the last name), and still in Vancouver reference styles but did not succeed. Little did I know that the style also ordered them by last name.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on tex.stackexchange. There are several small issues in your code:

1. It is far from being minimal
2. You should not write `\bibliography{\jobname.bib}` as the `.bib` is automatically added
3. You do not have to load `graphics` as it is already loaded by `graphicx`
4. You don't need the `filecontents` package as long as you use the related environment in the preamble
5. As said by @leandriis, if you want a reference list ordered by appearance, you should use an unsorted style, the prototype of whitch is `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`

The origin of you problem is the `\listoffigures`  which stands at the beginning and calls the `\cite{Dalheim2016}` to early.

Hence you could:

1. Remove the `\listoffigures`
2. Put it at the end
3. Last but not least use the optional argument of `\caption`, as this defines whay is put in `\listoffigures`. It is of course the real solution.

The minimal example :

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509567/listing-figure-citations-in-order-of-appearance-in-the-main-bibliography-list-o
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[numbers,round]{natbib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Hannan2013,
author = {Hannan, Nicholas R F and Segeritz, Charis-patricia and Touboul Thomas and Vallier, Ludovic},
doi = {10.1038/nprot.2012.153},
issn = {1754-2189},
journal = {Nat. Protoc.},
month = {feb},
number = {2},
pages = {430--437},
title = {{Production of hepatocyte-like cells from human pluripotent stem cells}},
volume = {8},
year = {2013}
}

@article{Lim1980,
author = {Lim, Franklin and Sun, Anthony M.},
doi = {10.1126/science.6776628},
issn = {00368075},
journal = {Science (80-. ).},
number = {4472},
pages = {908--910},
title = {{Microencapsulated islets as bioartificial endocrine pancreas}},
volume = {210},
year = {1980}
}

@article{Dalheim2016,
author = {Dalheim, Marianne and Vanacker, Julie and Najmi, Maryam A. and Aachmann, Finn L. and Strand, Berit L. and Christensen, Bj{\o}rn E.},
doi = {10.1016/j.biomaterials.2015.11.043},
issn = {18785905},
journal = {Biomaterials},
keywords = {Alginate,Cell adhesion,Periodate oxidation,RGD peptide,Reductive amination,Tissue engineering},
pages = {146--156},
title = {{Efficient functionalization of alginate biomaterials}},
volume = {80},
year = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
%------------DOCUMENT-----------
\begin{document}
{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
}

\chapter{Introduction} 
My very first reference \cite{Hannan2013}, 
and my second reference \cite{Lim1980}.

\chapter{Methods} 
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\qquad
\caption[Periodate oxidation (from Dalheim2016)]%
{Periodate oxidation \cite{Dalheim2016}.} 
\label{fig:periodateOx}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

By the way, the `unsrtnat` style does not handle neither doi nor issn  nor any kind or url. You will have to find another natbib-compatible which works with them, if you need. 
A possible solution :
add `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`in preable ans use 
`\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. An advantage of apacite is that the `.bbl` file contains formatting which is not hard-codded but relies on macros that you can easily customize with `\renewcommand`.

`